# Angular Json Looping

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi I am new to angular I have a requirment as follows.

app.js

```
$scope.fields = {
  "fields": {
    "LastName1": "ABC",
    "FirstName1": "XYZ",
    "LastName2": "123",
    "FirstName2": "345",
    "LastName3": "PQR",
    "FirstName3": "ASD",
    }
};
```

In my html I need to loop over this and display in

```
index.html
<tr ng-repeat="key in fields">
```

this doesn't seem to work. Please help.

I want my output as

```
LastName1   ABC
FirstName1  XYZ
```

and so on.

Also If user makes any changes to this, I want to be able to push the changes back to fields Json. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `(key, value) in object` syntax.

**In your case :**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in fields">
    <li ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value1">{{key2}} : {{value2}}</li>
</div>.
```

But :

> You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define
>   the order of keys returned for an object. (To mitigate this in Angular
>   1.3 the ngRepeat directive used to sort the keys alphabetically.)
>
> Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order
>   returned by the browser when running for key in myObj. It seems that
>   browsers generally follow the strategy of providing keys in the order
>   in which they were defined, although there are exceptions when keys
>   are deleted and reinstated. See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues
>
> If this is not desired, the recommended workaround is to convert your
>   object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer
>   before providing it to ngRepeat. You could do this with a filter such
>   as toArrayFilter or implement a $watch on the object yourself.

More details : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

---

**Edit : What if you want to change the object now ?**

**You can't do :**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in fields">
  <h3>{{key1}}</h2>
  <li ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value1">
    <input ng-model="value2" /><br />
    {{key2}} : {{value2}}
  </li>
</div>
```

Why ? Because ng-model will change `value2` in the current scope, and not in your object `fields` as you don't use **dot notation**.

> For each item/iteration, ng-repeat creates a new scope, which
>   prototypically inherits from the parent scope, but it also assigns the
>   item's value to a new property on the new child scope.

More details : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

But **you can do** :

```
<div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in fields">
  <h3>{{key1}}</h2>
  <li ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value1">
    <input ng-model="fields[key1][key2]" /><br />
    {{key2}} : {{value2}}
  </li>
</div>
```

[Take a look !!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/CqaC5ssibE1MehSiOzNa)

Comment: HI.. This worked for displaying. Now I am using text box to display the values.

If user makes changes to the Value in Text Box how do I update actual JSON.

Comment: That was not the question, but I updated my answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try change to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in fields.fields">
  <td>{{key}}</td>
  <td>{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a working plunker where you can update the model: http://jsfiddle.net/ttgfybk0/1/

Comment: Johnny is right, if you have only on property on the object `fields`, use only one ng-repeat (like this example).

Answer (score 0):

Repeat data is in object format like

```
{
  "LastName1": "ABC",
  "FirstName1": "XYZ",
  "LastName2": "123",
  "FirstName2": "345",
  "LastName3": "PQR",
  "FirstName3": "ASD",
}
```

use the `ng-repeat="(key, value) in expression"`

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in fields.fields">
  <td>{{key}} {{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

working example ishttp://plnkr.co/edit/Y5lPH1?p=preview